# Can't convert encoding from us-ascii to utf-8. What am screwing up?

Tags: encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to debug garbage characters that my webpages are rendering in foreign languages. I want my createpage.php in utf-8.

```
me@host:/www/webroot$ file -bi createpage.php
text/x-php; charset=us-ascii
me@host:/www/webroot$ iconv -f us-ascii -t utf-8 createpage.php > createpage_utf8.php
me@host:/www/webroot$ file -bi createpage_utf8.php
text/x-php; charset=us-ascii
```

I have `rwx` permessions on the directory, `rw` on the files. I must be blind - what am I screwing up here? Is it because ascii is a subset of utf-8 and my php doesn't have any special characters (just the ini files that I `include`), so `file -bi` just reports ascii anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A file using only plain ASCII characters is indistinguishable from UTF8, as by definition the 7-bit ASCII characters are mapped 1-to-1 in UTF8. Hence your "conversion" doesn't do anything.

Comment: Well I feel a little silly. I guess my problem lies with php's PDO module then, since all my tables are encoded in UTF-8. Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: Make sure that the webserver is passing on that the content is UTF-8 encoded, e.g. by adding a config line `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8`

Comment: `$db->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");` directly after opening the PDO connection to the database may help, with `mysql`.

Comment: All the relevant tables were already utf8 and the webserver was set to utf8, as were the http headers. It turns out I had just forgotten the `charset=utf8` argument when instantiating the PDO object.